# IPython: Configure Base Url Path for All Request

Tags: python, ipython

I am trying to figure out how to configure the base url of and IPython notebook server running.  So instead of the default:

```
#request# GET http://localhost:8888/static/tree/js/main.min.js?v=04a28c5e21950738efb217191f08ac33
#request# GET http://localhost:8888/api/terminals?_=1441754529652
#request# GET http://localhost:8888/custom/custom.js?v=20150908160654
#request# GET http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Untitled1.ipynb?kernel_name=python3#
```

I want to configure all requests so that the go through `ipython`, as in:

```
#request# GET http://localhost:8888/ipython/static/tree/js/main.min.js?v=04a28c5e21950738efb217191f08ac33
#request# GET http://localhost:8888/ipython/api/terminals?_=1441754529652
#request# GET http://localhost:8888/ipython/custom/custom.js?v=20150908160654
#request# GET http://localhost:8888/ipython/notebooks/Untitled1.ipynb?kernel_name=python3#
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To change the base url for the files that are being served up from iPython, edit the `ipython_notebook_config.py` file in your `~/.ipython/[profile-name]/` directory.

In particular, assuming that your config file starts with the line `c = get_config()`, you will want to add the following lines to your configuration:

```
c.NotebookApp.base_project_url = '/ipython/'
c.NotebookApp.base_kernel_url = '/ipython/'
c.NotebookApp.webapp_settings = {'static_url_prefix':'/ipython/static/'}
```

This will make it so that your project is served up from `http://localhost:8888/ipython/` instead of `http://localhost:8888/`.

For more information please see [this page of the ipython docs](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/public_server.html#running-with-a-different-url-prefix).

Comment: `NotebookApp.webapp_settings` is deprecated now

Comment: Will add to the above comment c.NotebookApp.base_project_url has also been depricated, it's now c.ServerApp.base_url